# Extract the value of Y axis at regular interval of 0.05 of x axis

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a data of two arrays. I want to plot the ROC_AUC curve and extract the value of y axis at regular interval of x axis. I am successful in plotting ROC curve but face difficulty to extract values at regular inteval of x axis.

This is my attempt:

```
import numpy
from matplotlib import pyplot

x = numpy.array([0,0,0,0.33333333,0.33333333,0.66666667,0.66666667,1,1])
y = numpy.array([0,0.05,0.8,0.8,0.85333,0.85333,0.912,0.912,1])
print(x)
print(y)

pyplot.plot(x, y, linestyle='--', color='navy', label='PTI')

for i,j in zip(x,y):
        pyplot.annotate(str(j),xy=(i,j))

# axis labels
pyplot.xlabel('False Positive Rate')
pyplot.ylabel('True Positive Rate')

pyplot.xticks(np.arange(min(x), max(x)+0.05, 0.05))

#show the legend
pyplot.legend()
  

#show the plot
pyplot.savefig('ROC', dpi = 500)
pyplot.show()
```

Rocplot:
[image]
My expected output text file should be:

```
 0             0
 0             0.05
 0             0.8 
 0.05          0.8
 0.10          0.8
 0.15          0.8
 0.20          0.8
 0.25          0.8
 0.30          0.8
 0.33333333    0.8
 0.33333333    0.85333
 0.35          0.85333 
 0.40          0.85333
 .             . 
 .             .
 .             .
 0.65          0.85333                   
 0.66666667    0.85333
 0.66666667    0.912   
 0.70          0.912
 .             .
 .             .
 1             0.912             
 1             1
```

Means if y = 0.8 at x = 0 and y = 0.8 at x = 0.0333; So value of y remains 0.8 between the range of x = 0.05, 0.10,1.15........0.03. same in the other interval of x.

Comment: AFAIK, there is nothing to do that in Numpy (nor probably any useful building-blocks). So you need to write this yourself using plain Python loops.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

interp1d from scipy can be used to interpret and resample the data - see the code below, however I have found that when resampling at 0.05, it is not enough to perfectly recreated your signal - this is indicated by the orange line on the graph, if this is not important than don't worry otherwise you need to sample at a higher rate to get perfectly spaced samples, see the green dashed line which is sampled at 0.005

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from scipy.interpolate import interp1d  


x = np.array([0,0,0,0.33333333,0.33333333,0.66666667,0.66666667,1,1])
y = np.array([0,0.05,0.8,0.8,0.85333,0.85333,0.912,0.912,1])

for x_, y_ in zip(x, y):
  print(x_, y_)

F = interp1d(x,y, kind = 'next')#, fill_value='nearest') 
times_resample_005 = np.arange(x.min(), x.max(), 0.05)
values_resample_005 = F(times_resample_005)

times_resample_0005 = np.arange(x.min(), x.max(), 0.005)
print(times_resample_0005[:10])
values_resample_0005 = F(times_resample_0005)


## ploting the data
fig, axs = plt.subplots(1, figsize=(10,10))
axs.plot(x,y, 'o')
axs.plot(times_resample_005,values_resample_005)
axs.plot(times_resample_0005,values_resample_0005, '--')
axs.set_xticks(np.arange(min(times), max(times)+0.05, 0.05))
print()
```

[image]